# JUnit 4.11 -> 4.12 introduced @Rule bug, doesn't executing tests

Tags: java, junit4

I switched from JUnit 4.11 to 4.12. Now I have a bug in the `@Rule` annotated method execution. My rule method looks like this:

```
@Rule
public WireMockRule testServer() {
    // ... other stuff gets created ...
    return new WireMockRule(
            wireMockConfig().extensions(...parameterized-extensions...).port(PORT), true);
}
```

Now, after starting, the rule method gets executed (fine), no test gets started **(not fine)**, but immediately the `testServer()` method gets executed *again*, *without* finishing the first one. So the test fails because the port got already bind and is still bound.

No problems in 4.11 with that. No configuration setup to run my tests in parallel. I should mention that my Test-Class is parametrized with `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`, but was executing in-order in 4.11.

Comment: Shouldn't it be an `@ClassRule` on a `static` method instead?

Comment: @M.Deinum No, because the extensions are parameterized.

Comment: @Jan: Is your `testServer()` function actually starting the test fixture? That seems wrong. A `TestRule` implementation shouldn't do any work when constructed, it should just decorate the test statements to add set up and tear down behaviors. I suspect your `WireMockRule` is starting the server too early.

Comment: @DanielPryden The main test fixture is created in a `@BeforeClass setUp()`, starting the server, deploying all ear's, starting messageQueue, etc.. The `WireMockRule` instead captures the resulting REST-Messages and checks them if they fit the expected data, corresponding to the currently tested parameter.

Comment: @Jan: OK, but it sounds like you're complaining that WireMockRule is instantiated multiple times when decorating Statements. That shouldn't be a problem unless the WireMockRule is doing work when instantiated. Instead it should defer the work until the Statements, if any, are executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the error and a simple fix. Just saw it with downloading the source-code of WireMockRule and debugging it.
It turns out that in JUnit 4.11 the `testServer()` method gets called *once* per parameter before the rule gets the `apply(...)` call to run the tests, in 4.12 it gets called always *twice* before the rule gets the `apply(...)` call to run the tests.
So the solution was simple:

```
private WireMockRule testServer;

@Rule
public WireMockRule testServer() {
    if (testServer != null) {
        return testServer;
    }
    // ... other stuff gets created ...
    testServer = new WireMockRule(
        wireMockConfig().extensions(...parameterized-extensions...).port(PORT), true);
    return testServer;
}
```